# how programmatically search on WhatsApp web in console

Tags: javascript

Why I can't search on WhatsApp web with this JavaScript code?

```
let xPath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]";
let result = document.evaluate(xPath, document);
let searchBox = result.iterateNext();
searchBox.innerText='my contact name'
```

It just shows **my contact name** in search box but it's **not filter** my contact.
How can I filter my contact after I enter my contact name in the search box?

Answer (score 0):

You have made it to the last step and got lost! The innerText is just the text you see not the inner text that filters the contacts. It is possible to change the innerHTML anywhere, but this type of textbox is not a native (typical) textbox that accepts being edited using the innerHTML property, uniquely listening (waiting) carefully for an event to happen then they work. So to do this here you have to use their weapon to fight them, use events.

## This is how to be done

```
function send_text(text) {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.setData('text', text);
    const event = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
        clipboardData: dataTransfer,
        bubbles: true
    });
    let el = document.querySelector('#main .copyable-area [contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
    el.focus()
    // select old text and replace it with new
    document.execCommand("selectall");
    el.dispatchEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: @cigien Is it wrong to ask for feedback? I have tested it on Chrome only and don't know if it works on other browsers.

Comment: Yes, asking for feedback leads to a more free-form discussion, which isn't appropriate on the site. To clarify, saying "Could you give me some feedback?" is too open-ended. On the other hand, you could certainly say something like you did in your comment, i.e. add text to the answer like "I have tested it on Chrome only and don't know if it works on other browsers". That's useful information for other users, and users may well leave a comment saying whether your solution works on other browsers as well.